# How I can read parameter PHP

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, web

How I can read this return of the parameter?

I have try to use the $_GET, it's working good for parameter like $_GET['name'], but for parameters like city, doesn't working... How's the best way to do this?

```
Object { name: "Test", city: Object }
city: Object
 city: Object
   city: "Bulls Gap"
   state_code: "TN"
org_name: "Test"
```

Thanks for any ideal!

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your json variable is $json, then you need to do like this:-

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->access_token(like name, city);// means $obj->name
```

Note:- Now city will be a std class object so try to convert into normal array and get your values.

Comment: What is `access_token()`...

Comment: i already wrote there